# Issues in author name in IEEE Double Column conference paper

Tags: xetex, two-column, ieeetran, author

I am facing problem writing author information in  IEEE Double Column Conference template can be found at https://www.ieee.org/conferences/publishing/templates.html
. I want to mention two things in author names, first, "equal contribution" and two,"corresponding author". I have used **\thanks{equal contribution}** , it shows the equal distribution at the bottom of the page. However, it does not show any symbol such as asterisk(*) on the author names. Then, I have tried **\footnote{equal contribution}**, simply nothing happens nowhere. Then I have used **\footnote[*]{equal contribution}**, it shows an asterisk beside the author name(with some error and warning), however, it does not show the text 'equal contribution' at the bottom of the page. I need show some symbols after the first author(such as *) and at the bottom of the page or near the names, the text "equal contribution".  Thank you. An sample code is given below since I cannot upload the cls file.

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\def\BibTeX{{\rm B\kern-.05em{\sc i\kern-.025em b}\kern-.08em
    T\kern-.1667em\lower.7ex\hbox{E}\kern-.125emX}}
\begin{document}

\title{Paper title here.}

\author{\IEEEauthorblockN{John Albert\thanks{equal contribution}, Author two, Author three, Author Four}
\IEEEauthorblockA{\textit{Dept. of CS} \\
 \textit{YYY University}\\
 City, Country \\
 Author1@email.com, Author2@email.com, Author3@email.com \\ Author4@email.com }
}
```

Comment: There is an example in page 6 of the IEEEtran manual.

Comment: BTW, I'm pretty sure a lot of those packages are redundant (already loaded).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the whole author block is implemented in a tabular, you would need `\footnotemark` and `\footnotetext` anyway.  But since `\thanks` turns off normal footnotes, you have to use `\IEEEauthorrefmark`, `\IEEEcompsocitemizethanks` and `\IEEEcompsocthanksitem` instead.

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\def\BibTeX{{\rm B\kern-.05em{\sc i\kern-.025em b}\kern-.08em
    T\kern-.1667em\lower.7ex\hbox{E}\kern-.125emX}}

\title{Paper title here.}

\author{\IEEEauthorblockN{John Albert\IEEEauthorrefmark{1}}
\IEEEcompsocitemizethanks{\IEEEcompsocthanksitem\IEEEauthorrefmark{1}equal contribution}
\IEEEauthorblockA{\textit{Dept. of CS} \\
 \textit{YYY University}\\
 City, Country \\
 Author1@email.com}
\and
\IEEEauthorblockN{author2} \\
\IEEEauthorblockA{Author2@email.com}
\and
\IEEEauthorblockN{author3} \\
\IEEEauthorblockA{Author3@email.com}
\and
\IEEEauthorblockN{autor4} \\
\IEEEauthorblockA{Author4@email.com}
}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\end{document}
```